# Как написать регулярное выражение, которое выделит все строки отвечающие заданым условиям?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Пишу регулярное выражение, которое позволяет выделить все строки отвечающие условиям:

- Состоят только из букв
- Одна и только одна из букв является заглавной

Пример строк которые могут быть выделены выражением:

```
"Мама",
"авТо",
"гриБ",
'Яблоко', 'яБлоко', 'ябЛоко', 'яблОко', 'яблоКо', 'яблокО'
```

Пример строк, которые не должны быть выделены выражением:

```
`агент007` - содержит цифры, 
"стриж" - только строчные буквы, 
"ГТО", - более одной заглавной буквы, 
`Три богатыря` - содержит пробел, допустимы только буквы
```

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
[а-я]*[А-Я][а-я]+?\S
```

Но все равно выделят слово "Три" в "Три богатыря".

Прверяю все через [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aGn8QC/2)

Comment: А вы сами то пробовали? Покажите, что у вас получилось, а что нет. А мы подправим.  А первым же постом на форуме просить решить задание вместо вас -  как-то не очень.

Comment: @MR.A Если только для русских букв - `re.fullmatch(r"[а-я]*[А-Я][а-я]*", text)`.

Comment: @ GrAnd    [а-я]*[А-Я][а-я]+?\S вот что у меня получилось но он все равно выделят слово 'три' (Три богатыря) проверяю все через https://regex101.com/r/aGn8QC/2

Answer (score 5):

По поводу попытки решения самостоятельно, попробуем разобрать ваше выражение и понять что не так:

```
[а-я]*[А-Я][а-я]+?\S
```

- не указа граница строки, т.е. начало - `^`
- Проблема квантификатора, в случае если последняя буква в слове будет заглавной `гриБ`, слово не будет захвачено, нужно поменять местами квантификаторы, но что бы это работало корректно добавить их в группу `(?:...|...)`
- Смягчение квантификатора не нужно `+?`
- `\S` - любой не пробельный символ, т.е. все кроме `\r\n\t\f\v` , вероятнее всего хотели указать любой пробельный символ `\s` - но под этот шаблон попадает как раз `Три` из `Три богатыря`, поэтому правильней использовать `$` - означающий конец строки

По итогу, если исправить все замечания, то получится такой шаблон:

```
^(?:[а-я]+[А-Я][а-я]*|[а-я]*[А-Я][а-я]+)$
```

Пример: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rktjVM/2)

Answer (score 1):

Про букву Ёё забыли и мне кажется, выражение выше можно его упростить:

`^([а-яё]*[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)$`

получается: в начале стоки любое кол-во строчных букв (от 0 до бесконечности), далее одна прописная буква, потом снова любое кол-во строчных букв

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Правильным выражением для паттерна в Python будет

`^[а-яёa-z]*[А-ЯЁA-Z]{1}[а-яёa-z]*$`

если разбирать паттерн, то логика такая -
строка может начинаться со строчных символов (кириллица или латиница) в кол-ве от нуля `[а-яёa-z]*`, далее должны встречаться прописные символы в кол-ве не более одного  `[А-ЯЁA-Z]{1}`, ну и после прописного символа должны быть только строчные в любом кол-ве от нуля  `[а-яёa-z]*`

Answer (score 0):

для `Python`:

```py
import re

  txt = "Три богатыря", "проверка"

  for x in txt:
    c = re.findall(r"(^[а-я]*[А-Я][а-я]*)$", x)
    print(c)
```

1. перебираем циклом все значения `txt`
2. c помощью метода `findall` ищем все схождения
3. задаем параметры поиска с одной заглавной буквой

Comment: Квантификатор `{1}` не имеет смысла

Comment: нет, `[...]` без квантификатора и будет является одним символом